# Set an If statement on a cell depending on the time frame

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm new here and currently I got an assignment in building up a Macro in Excel using VB. This is the logic I set up for a current cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

Range("D" & Target.Row) = Date

Range("E" & Target.Row) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

End If

End Sub
```

Every time someone enters information inside a cell in row B, it will automatically get the date and hour (kind of a log) when is entered. What I need is depending on the time frame I get on cell E, I need to get the shift that the information was computed based on the time frame from cell E into a different row.

- Shift 1 = 6:30am-2:30pm
- Shift 2 = 2:30pm - 11:30pm
- Shift 3 = 11:30pm - 6:30am

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an if statement so if e value greater than x and less then x then value = x ?

Comment: I just got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer, it was add up 3 If statements as the following:

```
If Time > TimeValue("6:30:00") And Time <= TimeValue("14:30:00") Then Range("F" & Target.Row) = "1st Shift"


If Time > TimeValue("14:30:01") And Time <= TimeValue("23:30:00") Then Range("F" & Target.Row) = "2nd Shift"


If Time > TimeValue("23:30:01") And Time <= TimeValue("6:30:00") Then Range("F" & Target.Row) = "Overtime"
```

Comment: Well done! Glad you got there, and you can take some satisfaction from sussing it out :). You can also consider turning the 3 IF statements into one, which would look like: If x > x And x < x Then x [newline] else if x > x And x < x Then x. Sorry about the poor syntax, but you can see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks. Yeah will try to just set up one statement, don't worry about the syntax it happens.